# Detection of radioactive iodine at trash dumps

Tags: radioactivity, particle-detectors

I have a cat that is getting radioactive iodine therapy and I am told I must flush the litter for 2 weeks because if I throw it away normally the dump will detect the radiation and fine me.

This seems pretty crazy to me. My understanding is that to detect the radioactivity from the cat you literally have to put the wand like 3 inches away from the litter. Also, I normally store my trash for 2-3 months before it gets sent to the center, so just from the half-life considerations alone it would seem unbelievable to me that it is detectable.

Is this just an empty threat to try to get me to flush the litter, or is it realistic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about concepts in physics.

Comment: Who told you this and have you checked your jurisdiction's laws? I agree that it seems hokey.